# Manim v0.2.0 self.play() method

Tags: manim

I cannot figure out how to create simple animations with the new Manim version (v0.2.0).
For example, I would like to move a circle to an edge and at the same time scale it.

In the previous versions I would have done as follows:

```
class CircleAnimations(Scene):

    def construct(self):
        circle = Circle()

        self.add(circle)
        self.play(
            circle.scale, 0.2,
            circle.to_edge, UP
        )

        self.wait()
```

But since in the new version, to animate in the `self.play` method we must use `mobj.animate.method(parameters)` , I tried to rewrite the `self.play` method as follows:

```
self.play(
    circle.animate.scale(0.2),
    circle.animate.to_edge(UP)
)
```

However this doesn't work: it seems to run only the first method, in this case, `circle.animate.scale(0.2)`, and not both `circle.animate.scale(0.2)` and `circle.animate.to_edge(UP)`

Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest the animations like this:

```py
self.play(
    circle.animate.scale(0.2).to_edge(UP)
)
```

Another way would be to use the `ApplyMethod` class:

```py
self.play(
    ApplyMethod(circle.scale, 0.2),
    ApplyMethod(circle.to_edge, UP)
)
```